# Publish site and compress javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, compression, publishing, compilation

Is there a way, that when I Publish/Compile my web application in Visual Studio 2010 that any javascript files in the application can be automatically compressed?

Comment: You can use a Post Build action with Minifiers running over your scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Web Deployment Tool [Visual Studio 2010 - WDP or Publish for automated deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085186/visual-studio-2010-wdp-or-publish-for-automated-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell my experience and maybe it serves to you.
When I build a web app, a consider use some content compressor, like [SquishIt](https://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher).
It has behaviors like compress when in production and cache files.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a nuget package to do this you might like to try ...

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/antix-nibbler

Uses YUI Compressor for .Net http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/ for JS and CSS 
and PNGOUT.EXE http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm for PNG compression

Doesn't combine the files into one like squishit does, but is easy to add to your app through nuget and needs no additional coding