# How to Publish Web with msbuild?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity, msdeploy

Visual Studio 2010 has a Publish command that allows you to publish your Web Application Project to a file system location. I'd like to do this on my TeamCity build server, so I need to do it with the solution runner or msbuild. I tried using the Publish target, but I think that might be for ClickOnce:

```
msbuild Project.csproj /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Deploy
```

I basically want to do exactly what a web deployment project does, but without the add-in. I need it to compile the WAP, remove any files unnecessary for execution, perform any [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx), and copy the output to a specified location.

**My Solution**, based on Jeff Siver's answer

```
<Target Name="Deploy">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" 
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package" 
             ContinueOnError="false" />
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectPath)\obj\$(Configuration)\Package\$(ProjectName).deploy.cmd&quot; /y /m:$(DeployServer) -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule" 
          ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162253/can-teamcity-publish-a-web-project-using-the-sln2008-build-runner

Comment: @SnOrfus I'm currently using Web Deployment Projects in VS 2008 (as I mentioned in my answer to that question) but I'd like to try automating the Publish feature of VS 2010 instead.

Comment: This question looks helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983575/copywebapplication-with-web-config-transformations/2953376#2953376

Comment: Just one little amendment to your script: you're using $(ProjectPath) for the deploy script but you really want is $(ProjectDir) otherwise you end up with .csproj\obj

Comment: @Troy Hunt - ProjectPath is actually a variable in my script that holds the relative path to the project folder, but ProjectDir should also work.

Comment: FYI Web Deployment Projectd are just MSBuild files, so to want the same behavior and not use them just means you'll be writing the MSBuild yourself. If you don't want to see in in VS then after you add it just remove it. WDP supports ASP.NET Compile/Merge which I see no mention of in any answer here.

Comment: Starting with VS2012, this is much easier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13947667/270348

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I got it mostly working without a custom msbuild script. Here are the relevant TeamCity build configuration settings:

```
Artifact paths: %system.teamcity.build.workingDir%\MyProject\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp 
Type of runner: MSBuild (Runner for MSBuild files) 
Build file path: MyProject\MyProject.csproj 
Working directory: same as checkout directory 
MSBuild version: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 
MSBuild ToolsVersion: 4.0 
Run platform: x86 
Targets: Package 
Command line parameters to MSBuild.exe: /p:Configuration=Debug
```

This will compile, package (with web.config transformation), and save the output as artifacts. The only thing missing is copying the output to a specified location, but that could be done either in another TeamCity build configuration with an artifact dependency or with an msbuild script.

**Update**

Here is an msbuild script that will compile, package (with web.config transformation), and copy the output to my staging server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
        <SolutionName>MySolution</SolutionName>
        <SolutionFile>$(SolutionName).sln</SolutionFile>
        <ProjectName>MyProject</ProjectName>
        <ProjectFile>$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName).csproj</ProjectFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="BuildPackage;CopyOutput" />

    <Target Name="BuildPackage">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
        <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)" ContinueOnError="false" Targets="Package" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CopyOutput">
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackagedFiles Include="$(ProjectName)\obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\**\*.*"/>
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(PackagedFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(PackagedFiles->'\\build02\wwwroot\$(ProjectName)\$(Configuration)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

You can also remove the SolutionName and ProjectName properties from the PropertyGroup tag and pass them to msbuild.

```
msbuild build.xml /p:Configuration=Deploy;SolutionName=MySolution;ProjectName=MyProject
```

**Update 2**

Since this question still gets a good deal of traffic, I thought it was worth updating my answer with my current script that uses [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) (also known as MSDeploy).

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <ProjectFile Condition=" '$(ProjectFile)' == '' ">$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName).csproj</ProjectFile>
    <DeployServiceUrl Condition=" '$(DeployServiceUrl)' == '' ">http://staging-server/MSDeployAgentService</DeployServiceUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="VerifyProperties">
    <!-- Verify that we have values for all required properties -->
    <Error Condition=" '$(ProjectName)' == '' " Text="ProjectName is required." />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="VerifyProperties">
    <!-- Deploy using windows authentication -->
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);
                             MvcBuildViews=False;
                             DeployOnBuild=true;
                             DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish;
                             CreatePackageOnPublish=True;
                             AllowUntrustedCertificate=True;
                             MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent;
                             MsDeployServiceUrl=$(DeployServiceUrl);
                             SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True;
                             UserName=;
                             Password=;"
             ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

In TeamCity, I have parameters named `env.Configuration`, `env.ProjectName` and `env.DeployServiceUrl`. The MSBuild runner has the build file path and the parameters are passed automagically (you don't have to specify them in Command line parameters).

You can also run it from the command line:

```
msbuild build.xml /p:Configuration=Staging;ProjectName=MyProject;DeployServiceUrl=http://staging-server/MSDeployAgentService
```

Comment: thanks - this also works well directly from powershell (apologies for the formatting - no carriage returns in comments): 
&msbuild "$solution" /p:"Configuration=$configuration"
; &msbuild "$project" /t:Package /p:"Configuration=$configuration;_PackageTempDir=$outputfolder"

Comment: I tried the example from your first Update and it seems that the `Package` target depends on WebDeploy, too: `error : Package/Publish task Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded failed to load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly installed on this machine.` (Mentioning it since you write that your second update uses WebDeploy, which might imply the first would not use WebDeploy yet.)

Comment: @jrummell: I want to deploy my Visual Studio web project to a remote Windows server from TeamCity. What should I do. I am a beginner and have no idea about what to to do

Comment: I'm able to get this to work on TeamCity with Web Application Projects, but I also have a legacy bound Website PROJECT that I also need to publish (as a package) then need to use MSDeploy.  If I publish within VS2013 I get a deployment package, but MSBuild from the cmd line does not create one.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions I'm not sure that this method will work with website projects. I've only tried it with web application projects.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure either feels like it should.  It works in Visual Studio and it does create a publish profile, it's just that msbuild itself doesn't seem to use it with the these switches.  Thanks.

Comment: How did you configure your visual studio solution to have a target:package section in the project build files?

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions recent versions of Visual Studio will now create publish profiles for Website projects. Since Website project doesn't have a project file a Websitepublish.proj (not 100% on the name here) which can be used in place of the .csproj file in this case.

Comment: A couple  more interesting properties to consider when publishing: FilesToIncludeForPublish=AllFilesInProjectFolder;ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol=true;

Comment: I don't see any mention of the publish profile in this.  Publish profile should be specified so the correct web.config transform is applied. Update: Nevermind... that feature was introduced 2 years after this post. This one still probably works.  Later post in this thread shows how to publish with a publish profile from command line.

Comment: @Triynko that's correct. The preferred way now is with a publish profile as shown in Chris' answer.

Comment: I have same issue , Please check with this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68952592/how-to-publish-multiple-project-csproj-file-with-individual-folder-using-msbu

Answer (score 92):

Using the deployment profiles introduced in VS 2012, you can publish with the following command line:

```
msbuild MyProject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name> /p:Password=<insert-password> /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```

For more information on the parameters [see this](https://web.archive.org/web/20191003075438/http://sedodream.com/2013/01/06/CommandLineWebProjectPublishing.aspx).

The values for the `/p:VisualStudioVersion` parameter depend on your version of Visual Studio. Wikipedia has a [table of Visual Studio releases and their versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#History).

Comment: Using VS2012 .NET 3.5, this did not work for deploying to the file system.  It simply builds and does no deployment.

Comment: your /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 saved my life. I use /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 for vs2013 and its works fine.

Comment: What will be the value for `/p:VisualStudioVersion=?` for VS 2017?

Comment: created build script  `msbuild test.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=.\build_output1\pub /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:outdir=.\build_output1`       ......But still getting only DLLs not all the files like in publish folder :(`

Comment: @Nishant For VS 2017, use `/p:VisualStudioVersion=15`. I am not sure if this is related to your file copying issue.

Answer (score 43):

I came up with such solution, works great for me:

```
msbuild /t:ResolveReferences;_WPPCopyWebApplication /p:BuildingProject=true;OutDir=C:\Temp\build\ Test.csproj
```

The secret sauce is _WPPCopyWebApplication target.

Comment: What is _WPPCopyWebApplication and how can I use it MSBbuild xml config file/

Comment: Using VS2012 .NET 3.5, I got the error `error MSB4057: The target "_WPPCopyWebApplication" does not exist in the project`.  Taking out that part led to a deployment without deploying any views

Comment: You might need to call it with a different /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 because build uses the targets from c:\program files (x86)\msbuild\microsoft\visualstudio\VERSION\Webapplication\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets so maybe its using an older version that doesnt have the correct target.

Comment: @FRoZeN I tried using MSBuild as `MSBuild.exe C:\BuildAgent\work\4c7b8ac8bc7d723e\WebService.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=bin /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://204.158.674.5/msdeploy.axd /p:username=Admin /p:password=Password#321 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployIisAppPath=Default WebSite/New /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC`. It gives me an error  `MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified. Switch: WebSite/New`. Is there a  solution for this?

Comment: @NevinRajVictor that error is likely because you have a space in the DeployIisAppPath value. You will need to put the value in quotes.  e.g. /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Website/New"

Answer (score 29):

I don't know TeamCity so I hope this can work for you.

The best way I've found to do this is with MSDeploy.exe.  This is part of the WebDeploy project run by Microsoft.  You can download the bits [here](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy).

With WebDeploy, you run the command line

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:contentPath=c:\webApp -dest:contentPath=c:\DeployedWebApp
```

This does the same thing as the VS Publish command, copying only the necessary bits to the deployment folder.

Comment: That looks promising. However, it looks like the Management Service is only available on Server 2008. My staging server (where I want to automate deployment) is running Windows 7 Pro.

Comment: There are two pieces to the product.  The pieces that integrate right into IIS require Server 2008.  The command line component does not have that requirement; I have it running on a Server 2003 box I use for deployments.

Comment: I've done some reading on MSDeploy. I got it installed and working on my staging server, thanks! Can I run MSDeploy from an MSBuild script?

Comment: It should run fine as an EXEC task in your build script.

Comment: does the same thing as which configuration of the VS Publish command? Which publish method - file system or other? Does it use the MyProject.Publish.xml file to determine which files to copy?

Comment: I just gave it a shot but it did not do the same as VS Publish. It did the same as XCopy including all source files.

Answer (score 13):

With VisualStudio 2012 there is a way to handle subj without publish profiles. You can pass output folder using parameters. It works both with absolute and relative path in 'publishUrl' parameter. You can use VS100COMNTOOLS, however you need to override VisualStudioVersion to use target 'WebPublish' from `%ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`. With VisualStudioVersion 10.0 this script will succeed with no outputs :)

**Update:** I've managed to use this method on a build server with just Windows SDK 7.1 installed (no Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 on a machine). But I had to follow these steps to make it work:

1. Make Windows SDK 7.1 current on a machine using Simmo answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2907056/2164198)
2. Setting Registry Key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7\10.0 to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\" (use your path as appropriate)
3. Copying folder %ProgramFiles%\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0 from my developer machine to build server

Script:

```
set WORK_DIR=%~dp0
pushd %WORK_DIR%
set OUTPUTS=%WORK_DIR%..\Outputs
set CONFIG=%~1
if "%CONFIG%"=="" set CONFIG=Release
set VSTOOLS="%VS100COMNTOOLS%"
if %VSTOOLS%=="" set "PATH=%PATH%;%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" && goto skipvsinit
call "%VSTOOLS:~1,-1%vsvars32.bat"
if errorlevel 1 goto end
:skipvsinit
msbuild.exe Project.csproj /t:WebPublish /p:Configuration=%CONFIG% /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl=%OUTPUTS%\Project
if errorlevel 1 goto end
:end
popd
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution -- this is what I was looking for: the WebPublish option with file system deployment.

Answer (score 12):

found two different solutions which worked in slightly different way:

1. This solution is inspired by the answer from alexanderb [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764639/2066007). Unfortunately it did not work for us - some dll's were not copied to the OutDir. We found out that replacing `ResolveReferences` with `Build` target solves the problem - now all necessary files are copied into the OutDir location.

```
msbuild /target:Build;_WPPCopyWebApplication  /p:Configuration=Release;OutDir=C:\Tmp\myApp\ MyApp.csproj
```

Disadvantage of this solution was the fact that OutDir contained not only files for publish.

2. The first solution works well but not as we expected. We wanted to have the publish functionality as it is in Visual Studio IDE - i.e. only the files which should be published will be copied into the Output directory. As it has been already mentioned first solution copies much more files into the OutDir - the website for publish is then stored in `_PublishedWebsites/{ProjectName}` subfolder. The following command solves this - only the files for publish will be copied to desired folder. So now you have directory which can be directly published - in comparison with the first solution you will save some space on hard drive.

```
msbuild /target:Build;PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:Configuration=Release;_PackageTempDir=C:\Tmp\myApp\;AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false MyApp.csproj
```

`AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false` parameter will guarantee that connection strings will not be handled as special artifacts and will be correctly generated - for more information see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4151829).

Comment: Your option #2 helped me seamlessly get rid of the obsolete _CopyWebApplication. You rescued my Build-Server after upgrade to VS 2015. Great research. Appreciative.

Comment: Your option #2 was perfect for my build script.

Answer (score 6):

this is my working batch

**publish-my-website.bat**

```
SET MSBUILD_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
SET PUBLISH_DIRECTORY="C:\MyWebsitePublished"
SET PROJECT="D:\Github\MyWebSite.csproj"


cd /d %MSBUILD_PATH%
MSBuild %PROJECT%  /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=%PUBLISH_DIRECTORY%
```

Note that I installed Visual Studio on server to be able to run `MsBuild.exe` because the `MsBuild.exe` in .Net Framework folders don't work.

Comment: `msbuild test.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=.\build_output1\pub /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0 /p:outdir=.\build_output1`       ......But still getting only DLLs not the files structure i want. Whats wrong with it? :(

Answer (score 3):

You must set your environments

- < WebSite name>
- < domain>

and reference my blog.(sorry post was Korean)

- http://xyz37.blog.me/50124665657
- http://blog.naver.com/PostSearchList.nhn?SearchText=webdeploy&blogId=xyz37&x=25&y=7

  ```
  @ECHO OFF
  :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598668/valid-parameters-for-msdeploy-via-msbuild
  ::-DeployOnBuild -True
  :: -False
  :: 
  ::-DeployTarget -MsDeployPublish
  :: -Package
  :: 
  ::-Configuration -Name of a valid solution configuration
  :: 
  ::-CreatePackageOnPublish -True
  :: -False
  :: 
  ::-DeployIisAppPath -<Web Site Name>/<Folder>
  :: 
  ::-MsDeployServiceUrl -Location of MSDeploy installation you want to use
  :: 
  ::-MsDeployPublishMethod -WMSVC (Web Management Service)
  :: -RemoteAgent
  :: 
  ::-AllowUntrustedCertificate (used with self-signed SSL certificates) -True
  :: -False
  :: 
  ::-UserName
  ::-Password
  SETLOCAL

  IF EXIST "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727" SET FXPath="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727"
  IF EXIST "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5" SET FXPath="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5"
  IF EXIST "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" SET FXPath="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"

  SET targetFile=<web site fullPath ie. .\trunk\WebServer\WebServer.csproj
  SET configuration=Release
  SET msDeployServiceUrl=https://<domain>:8172/MsDeploy.axd
  SET msDeploySite="<WebSite name>"
  SET userName="WebDeploy"
  SET password=%USERNAME%
  SET platform=AnyCPU
  SET msbuild=%FXPath%\MSBuild.exe /MaxCpuCount:%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% /clp:ShowCommandLine

  %MSBuild% %targetFile% /p:configuration=%configuration%;Platform=%platform% /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False /p:DeployIISAppPath=%msDeploySite% /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=%msDeployServiceUrl% /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:UserName=%USERNAME% /p:Password=%password% /p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0

  IF NOT "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" PAUSE 
  ENDLOCAL
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can Publish the Solution with desired path by below code, Here PublishInDFolder is the name that has the path where we need to publish(we need to create this in below pic)

[You can create publish file like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8a0p.png)

Add below 2 lines of code in batch file(.bat)

```
@echo OFF 
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsMSBuildCmd.bat"
MSBuild.exe  D:\\Solution\\DataLink.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=PublishInDFolder
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

This my batch file

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\Projects\testPublish\testPublish.csproj  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /property:Configuration=Release
if exist "C:\PublishDirectory" rd /q /s "C:\PublishDirectory"
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p C:\Projects\testPublish\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp -c C:\PublishDirectory
cd C:\PublishDirectory\bin 
del *.xml
del *.pdb
```

Comment: It would be great if you could detail your answer. How exactly does your batch file solves the OP's issue? Thanks!

Comment: @LuísCruz, I assume he uses aspnet_compiler tool for deploy

Answer (score 1):

For generating the publish output provide one more parameter.
msbuild example.sln /p:publishprofile=profilename /p:deployonbuild=true /p:configuration=debug/or any

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command to publish web applications with Publish Profiles.

```
msbuild SolutionName.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=PublishProfileName
```

This sample Publish Profile can create a release zip file with a version number that's in AssemblyInfo.cs File in the network path (create zip file and remove other published files with PowerShell command is optional).

```
 <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
     <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <Major>0</Major>
    <Minor>1</Minor>
    <Build>2</Build>
    <Publish>C:\</Publish>
    <publishUrl>$(Publish)</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="GetBuildUrl">
    <PropertyGroup>      <In>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs'))</In>
      <TargetPath>\\NetworkPath\ProjectName</TargetPath>
      <Pattern>^\s*\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(\D*(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)</Pattern>
      <Major>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[1].Value)</Major>
      <Minor>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[2].Value)</Minor>
      <Build>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[3].Value)</Build>
      <Sub>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(In), $(Pattern), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups[4].Value)</Sub>
      <Publish>$(TargetPath)\$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build).$(Sub)\</Publish>
      <publishUrl Condition=" '$(Publish)' != '' ">$(Publish)</publishUrl>
      <publishUrl Condition=" '$(Publish)' == '' and '$(LastUsedBuildConfiguration)'!='' ">$(LastUsedBuildConfiguration)</publishUrl>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="GetBuildUrl">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="|" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text=" ================================================================================================" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="    BUILD INFO                                                                                    " />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="    Version [$(Major).$(Minor).$(Build)] found in [$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs] " />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="    Build will be saved to [$(publishUrl)]                                                        " />
    <Message Importance="High" Text=" =================================================================================================" />
    <Message Importance="High" Text="|" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Zip" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="PowerShell -command Compress-Archive -Path $(Publish) -DestinationPath $(Publish)Release.zip" />
    <Exec Command="PowerShell -command Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $(Publish) -Exclude Release.zip" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

With PublishProfile:

```
msbuild SolutionName.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=PublishProfileName
```

Without PublishProfile:

```
msbuild SolutionName.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true p:DeployDefaultTarget=WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:publishUrl=.\releaseFolderName
```