# Web Deploy ignores SkipExtraFilesOnServer set by MSBuild

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, package, msdeploy

I'm using MSBuild to create a Web Deploy Package on our CruiseControl Server to Deploy our web applications. On deployment everything not in the package will be deleted on our servers.

I tried the option SkipExtraFilesOnServer option set to true. But it is ignored by Web Deploy

```
<Target Name="CreateDeploymentPackage">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(Web)" Targets="Package"
      properties="Platform=$(Platform);
      Configuration=$(Configuration);
      DeployOnBuild=False;
      DeployTarget=Package;
      SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True;
      MSDeployUseChecksum=True;
      PackageLocation=$(DeployDirectory)\_PublishedWebsites\DeployPackage\$(CurrentProject).zip;
      PackageAsSingleFile=True;
      _PackageTempDir=$(PackageOutputDir)\temp;">
    </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

Why is this not working? Every documentation I find says it should.

Comment: I think that 'SkipExtraFilesOnServer' is only used when deploying directly from MSBuild (DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish). The setting is not included with deploy packages.

Comment: @StevenLiekens no it applies (though it's poorly named for the package case). I think he's running into something else, I've answered below.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi aren't you one of the guys who created web deploy?

Comment: @spankmaster79 do you use the deploy script that is generated, or do you execute msdeploy.exe directly from an `exec` task in CruiseControl?

Comment: @StevenLiekens I own the Web Publish experience in Visual Studio which is built on top of MSDeploy as well as other tech, but I don't work on MSDeploy directly.

Comment: I'm using the .cmd that is created along with the package

Comment: @spankmaster79 double check the command its executing, you may need to edit to add that in the .cmd file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not following you 100% but, I think I understand what's happening here. Here is my understanding of your situation.

You've configured your build server to do the following.

1. Build a web deploy package using msbuild.exe
2. You've set `SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true` when creating the package
3. Publish the web deploy package using msdeploy.exe

The issue that you are likely running into is when the package is published to the server. When pass `SkipExtraFilesOnServer=true` is translated to the msdeploy option `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule`. Which is applied (and relevant) when publishing **to the package** in your case. Now you need to ensure that option is set when the package is published **to the server**. That option is not embedded in the package in anyway.

Comment: How would you handle the case where the package is imported in IIS manager instead of using the helper script that is generated?

Comment: @StevenLiekens I used the UI but not recently, isn't there an option to leave the other files? If not that's no good.

Comment: It seems the DoNotDelete rule is not applied when creating the package with MSBuild. When manually adding it to the executed .cmd it actually works

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi should the .cmd file contain the `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` command option? I don't see it in there.

Comment: adding the rule manually works. So I would recommend this solution

Answer (score 2):

You can affect the generated `.publish.cmd` file by setting different properties. If you want to translate the `SkipExtraFilesOnServer` property into `-enableRule:DotNotDeleteRule`, you can add this to your `.csproj`-file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <_GenerateSampleDeployScript_AfterSet_Destination
      Condition="$(SkipExtraFilesOnServer) == 'True'">
    set _MsDeployAdditionalFlags=%_MsDeployAdditionalFlags% -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
  </_GenerateSampleDeployScript_AfterSet_Destination>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It will add the `-enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule` argument to msdeply, whenever the package is generated with the `SkipExtraFilesOnServer` property set to `True`.