# Visual studio 2010 publish command - command prompt

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, devenv

I am using the batch script below to build a solution file

```
set BUILD_PATH=%CD%

call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"

devenv /clean Release "%BUILD_PATH%\Source\Dotnet\WebService\OPALController\OPALController.sln"

devenv /rebuild Release "%BUILD_PATH%\Source\Dotnet\WebService\OPALController\OPALController.sln
```

I was searching for a command to publish, since `devenv /publish` is not working

Is there any other way publish the artifacts?

Comment: You may want to consider Web Deploy (MSDeploy). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a **Visual Studio 2010 Web Deployment Project** to your solution and then publish using that.

If you follow the directions found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/automated-deployments-teamcity), but instead of using the TeamCity Build Runner you call MSBuild directly from your batch file you might be able to publish using the **/p:Configuration=Deployment** switch.

So basically your steps would be:
1) Download and install the [**Visual Studio 2010 Web Deployment Projects**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24509)
2) Add a web deployment project to your solution
3) Create a **"Deployment"** configuration for your project(s) as outlined in the article
4) Call **MSBuild** from your script to compile your solution with the **/target:REBUILD** and **/p:Configuration=Deployment** switches