# Is it possible to change the Build Action of a file in pre-build events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want a file (robots.txt) to only publish when I am using a certain build configuration.  Is there a way to handle this in pre-build events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An other option would be to use the $(ConfigurationName) macro within the VisualStudio build events editor:

```
if $(ConfigurationName)=="Production" copy robots.txt destinationpath
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this. Two things that you may need to do:

- Manual fiddling with the .proj file in text editor (or Visual Studio when project is unloaded)
- Use of MSBUILD conditional execution

Sample code to get you started. Adjust it at will

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Production'">
     <Copy 
            SourceFiles=".../robot.txt" 
            DestinationFolder="..."/>
</Target>
```

Comment: I can do that to copy the file but I need it to be included when publishing the site.  Forgot to mention I am using VS to publish.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that from VS... You can extract a [publish task](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12221999/706456) or something that looks very close to it. I usually have a /build folder, where I put MS Build scripts. For web projects I add a publish.bat file, that calls MS BUILD script with publish params. So when I just click on that file it does the job. I tried to do similar things from VS, never got it running. It turned out to be much easier to use external script and bat files for me.