# How to Deploy C# .net application with MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am new to mongoDB. I would like to ask for help about deployment of a C# .net app with MongoDB. I tried to publish it but when I run, it goes not working. I know the error is that I need to manually run mongod.exe through C:/mongodb/bin/mongod. But how can I setup it without manually run the mongod.exe? Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand that your .NET application and Mongo database are different parts of the system. They even can be placed on different machines. So, publish of your application shouldn't affect availability of database.
However you can combine these two actions in one simple batch file:

```
msbuild.exe [your app with necessary options]
C:/mongodb/bin/mongod.exe [options]
```

On how to build and deploy web-apps via **msbuild** you can see here:

- [How to Publish Web with msbuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild)
  [Invoke a publish from msbuild for visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221999/invoke-a-publish-from-msbuild-for-visual-studio-2012)
- [Invoke a publish from msbuild for visual studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221999/invoke-a-publish-from-msbuild-for-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to set up mongodb to run as a windows service, rather than manually starting the server on demand.

Instructions can be found here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/