# Use subversion to manage code deployment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, svn, version-control

I have 4 web servers in a cluster that need to all have the same code on it and pushing code to each server seems to be a tedious task. I was wondering if it is good or bad practice to use subversion to manage asp.net & MVC code deployments. My deployments would go from copy/pasting files to each server to just doing svn update at the webroot of each server. Is there any good reason why this would be a bad idea? I apologize if this is the wrong place for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use SVN to keep your servers up to date. However, I would take it one step further and use [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Integration#Automate_deployment). Long story short, you would need to set up a Continuous Integration server such as [CCNet](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki) or [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) that will automate your build and deployment process so that you can release your updates to all servers with only a few clicks.

Comment: I'm actually using CruiseControl.net for that but I wanted to create a build task that executes svn update on the remote servers

Comment: It's been a while since I've used CCNet, but I would recommend using MS Web Deploy instead of SVN update. See this question for a working [MSBuild script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3098613/26226).

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. You can pre-compile everything for deployment, instead of just doing a copy deploy. This will catch compile-time errors which would otherwise go unnoticed until the first time someone hits the website.