# how to publish asp.net website with solution file instead of .csproj file using msbuild

Tags: asp.net, msbuild

I want to publish asp.net web site using solution file because my site is not containing .csproj file.

how to write msbuild scripts

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild

Comment: thanks for reply.actually i have web site project and it does't have .csproj file so in this case i am not able to publish my web site project using msbuild scripts in vs2010 commandline .pls suggest me alternate solution

Comment: You can do it directly by pointing to solution file not .csproj file.

Comment: hi sunny.i have tryied in vs2010 command line but i am getting percompiler error.could you please share me correct tested scipts.my scripts is 

  <Target Name="PublishToFile">
    <MSBuild Targets="PublishToFileSystem" Properties="Platform=AnyCPU;Configuration=Release;PublishDestination=$(PublishPath)" Projects="$(CheckOutPath)\$(ProjectFilePath)\$(ProjectFile)"/>
  </Target>