# Can we do a file system publish of ASP.NET projects using Powershell?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, publish

I use IIS Manager 6.1 to run my virtual Website.
I want to Publish my website and generate dlls using powershell script.
Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild