# Deploying Multiple Projects in Same Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution that contains **Web**, **Admin**, couple of class and data access projects. Main project is **Web**. I am using **Admin** project as area under **Web**. **Admin** project's physical folder is under **Web**/Administration folder. But when i try to publish **Web** project, it publishes **Web** project and add other data access or class projects as dlls to bin folder, but neither **Admin** project being published nor it's dll being added to bin folder.

```
Solution
--- Data (Library)
--- Service (Library)
--- Admin (Area) *MVC Web*
--- Web (Main) *MVC Web*
--- Framework (Library)
```

What am i missing here?

PS: Please tell me if you need more info to help. I am really desperate here.

Answer (score 0):

**Web** is a separate web application, so if you want to publish that one too, you'll have to publish it separately. The only way you could include it as a .dll in the bin folder of **Web** is if you'd include it as a reference to the **Web** project. But then it would just be used as a class library, not as a separate web application.

Comment: Admin project referenced to Web and i am using it as area under Web project. Web is my main project and i want that when i publish Web project, also admin project needs to be published under it's physical folder (Web/Administration) under Web project.

Comment: If you want it to be published under its physical location, you'll have to import it as a folder in the Web project and make it "always copy" upon built. Then it'll be exported to the /bin folder at each build.

Comment: But it is a seperate project. How it works if i also import it's physical folder under Web project?

Comment: In [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1139669/How-to-Create-an-Area-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Application) areas are added in the same project as the root web application. So are you sure you area has to be in a seperate project? But maybe [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900246/how-to-publish-an-asp-net-mvc-4-application-with-areas) might help you.