# Visual Studio script - creating an automatic version

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to do the following steps automatically:

1. Publish a web project from my solution.
2. Compile another project from my solution.
3. Put both projects in a folder together.

*Both projects need to have an auto-increment version control(Same version number for both).

Any ideas? using a post-after build batch files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [msbuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452(v=vs.90).aspx) for that.

you can find an example to publish with MSBuild [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild)

Comment: Not what i am looking for, need it all in a batch file. I saw https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20w810z.aspx . Is it possible to run this tool from CMD

Comment: Yes. You can call the MS build from a command line and you can call it from post/pre-build too. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms164311.aspx