# MS Web Deploy creating new folder under Web Site?

Tags: msbuild, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am using the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097489/how-to-publish-web-with-msbuild/15387814#15387814) to deploy MVC5 application to IIS 8. In IIS i have a web site "Default Web Site" which is pointed to physical location "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite"
My build file look like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
          <PropertyGroup>
            <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
            <ProjectFile Condition=" '$(ProjectFile)' == '' ">.\UI\$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName).csproj</ProjectFile>
            <DeployServiceUrl Condition=" '$(DeployServiceUrl)' == '' ">http://localhost</DeployServiceUrl>
          </PropertyGroup>

          <Target Name="VerifyProperties">
            <!-- Verify that we have values for all required properties -->
            <Error Condition=" '$(ProjectName)' == '' " Text="ProjectName is required." />
          </Target>

          <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="VerifyProperties">
            <!-- Deploy using windows authentication -->
            <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)"
                     Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);
                                     MvcBuildViews=False;
                                     DeployOnBuild=true;
                                     DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish;
                                     CreatePackageOnPublish=True;
                                     AllowUntrustedCertificate=True;
                                     MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent;
                                     MsDeployServiceUrl=$(DeployServiceUrl);
                                     SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True;
                                     UserName=;
                                     Password=;"
                     ContinueOnError="false" />
          </Target>
        </Project>
```

I'm running the following command to build & deploy

```
msbuild build.xml /p:Configuration=Release;ProjectName=MyProjectName;DeployServiceUrl=http://localhost
```

The command builds the project and deploys the project. However it is not deploying the project directly under "Default Web Site" instead its creating a new application under "Default Web Site" with the name **"MyProjectName_deploy"** and this application is pointing to new physical location. **"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite\MyProjectName_deploy"**

I want the code to deploy directly to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mywebsite where "Default Web Site" is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your build file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site</DeployIisAppPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Related details -
https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/03/simple-service-versioning-with-webdeploy/